# Rails 3: Retrieve all objects that have a certain value NOT equal to another value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called `Review` and i want to retrieve all review objects that don't have `:stage` equal to `"approve"`.

so something like this: `Review.where(:stage not_equal_to "approve")`

How can i actually do this? and where can i find the list of calls i can make inside the `.where` such as less than, greater than etc.

Comment: if you want something more complex but useful , you can take a look to Metawhere[http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/] gem which has greater than, less than ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using pure string condition queries, which are documented in the Rails Guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#pure-string-conditions.

```
Review.where("stage != ?", "approve")
```

This can be vulnerable to SQL queries if you go using user values in the string condition, so use the array syntax as above, which replaces the question marks with each passed argument after sanitization.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use

```
Review.where("stage <> 'approve'")
```

This string will be directly used in SQL in the where clause. Be very careful not to do `Review.where("stage <> #{var}")` as its vulnerable to sql injection, rather, use `Review.where("stage <> ?", var)`

Comment: thats didnt work, it gave this error: ``ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'approve' in 'where clause': SELECT `reviews`.* FROM `reviews` WHERE (stage <> approve)``

Comment: edited, try now (i forgot to add the single quote around approve so mysql interpreted approve as a keyword or a column name, another common mistake you should avoid)